# WebStorm: After opening another workspace/window can't type in editor LINUX

Tags: text-editor, webstorm

Okay so I have this problem(which strange enough also happens within idea `ide`) that when I change between `workspaces/windows`, I suddenly(when changing back to the `webstorm` editor) can't enter text anymore. 
This forces me to restart the application.

Is there a way to fix this without restarting the application each time again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this bug in Ubuntu 13.10.

The workaround I have come up with is to kill ibus-daemon

```
killall ibus-daemon
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and Webstorm 2016.1. Any explanation for what's happening here? How did you figure it out?

Comment: @foobarbecue Sorry, but I have no idea. One day I was sufficiently annoyed by it to try just see if anything worked and killing things that could be related and let them restart was a desperate part of that.